# Updating sql database with pdo

Tags: sql, database, pdo

I am trying to update some database values with this code

```
public function updateImprovement($id, $improveId, $body) {

    //UPDATE ITC
  $update = ("UPDATE as_improvement SET value = :value WHERE id = :id");

  $statement = $this->db-> prepare($update);

    $statement -> bindValue( ":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $statement -> bindValue( ":value", $body, PDO::PARAM_STR );


    $statement -> execute();

    //UPDATE IMPROVE
    $update = ("UPDATE as_improve SET content_new = :content_new AND approved = 1 WHERE id = :improveId");

  $statement = $this->db-> prepare($update);


    $statement -> bindValue( ":improveId", $improveId, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $statement -> bindValue( ":content_new", $body, PDO::PARAM_STR );



    $statement -> execute();

}
```

The problem is in the "content_new" -> (content_new = :content_new) variable, since without it, the sql sentence is perfectly executed. Can I use $body twice in two sentences?

Comment: shouldn't the seconde query be like this? `UPDATE as_improve SET content_new = :content_new,approved = 1 WHERE id = :improveId`

Comment: Oh man, must have missed that completely. Thanks for your help, it works now! :)

Comment: Where is the jQuery here???

Comment: this is unrelated to jQuery. Did you mean PHP?

Comment: @empiric Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You were running `content_new = :content_new AND approved = 1`

It should be: `content_new = :content_new, approved = 1`

however, I have re jigged it a little for you:

```
public function updateImprovement($id, $improveId, $body) {

    //UPDATE ITC
    $update = ("UPDATE as_improvement SET value = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $statement = $this->db-> prepare($update);
    $statement->execute([$body, $id]);

    //UPDATE IMPROVE
    $update = ("UPDATE as_improve SET content_new = ?, approved = 1 WHERE id = ?");
    $statement = $this->db-> prepare($update);
    $statement->execute([$body, $improveId]);
}
```